# django subdomains a la craigslist.com

Tags: django

I am interested in setting up my application so that I can serve location specific content.

Something like craigslist, where miami.craigslist.org only shows posts in miami.

Assuming that I have a model that has a City field, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Banjer suggested the Sites framework, but I feel like it might not be a 100% perfect fit for your situation. The sites framework works well for different sites sharing the same database. But in your case, its all the same site and you are basically just wanting to pass an argument to your views for the city.

You could probably do something even simpler by just pointing wildcard `*.domain.com` to your django site, and then using `request.get_host()` in the view to parse out the subdomain:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host

So if the domain were: "losangeles.domain.com", and you parsed out "losangeles", you could use that as your city "tag" in your query. And when you create new content, you can just tag it with a city.

```
Post.objects.filter(city_tag="losangeles")
```

I suppose it depends on how robust of a "location" structure you need in your site. It very well might be a `City` model with various meta data fields, including the `tag` field. Then you would associate it with the content as a foreign key. It kind of approaches the same general idea as the Sites framework, but in this case you aren't really creating different sites.

Comment: If I decide to go this way, it is probable that multiple views will depend on the city... Is there anyway of having the site pre-process the subdomain, and filter all models across every view?

Comment: @alexBrand: You might consider parsing the subdomain in middleware and attaching it to the session. That would at least simplify your urls.py file. As for automagically adding this to a filter on models, that feels sort of like a global variable -- they can be useful, but sometimes making debugging a bitch (Hidden Actor). If you go that route, document the snot out of it for the next poor bastard to work on the site. :-)

Comment: Would you rather use a mod_rewrite to direct city.site.com to site.com/city? That is another idea

Comment: @alexBrand: I agree with Peter about the middleware, but I don't see how it affects the urls.py. Anyways, doing any kind of modifications to the models might be just a can of worms. It would be easiest to just create a utility function for your views to query based on the request object. Let that central function take the city tag into consideration and filter the models. Don't put any kind of restrictions onto the models themselves. Just create a layer in between that is centralized and controlled.

Comment: How would I go about doing that centralization?

Comment: @alexBrand: Really all I meant was creating like a utils.py module or some controller module and creating helper functions in there to reuse across your views. Then in a view you could do getLocalPosts(request)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the ["sites" framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/).  If you've ever used the built-in Django admin, then you've probably seen the sites section where example.com is the only site listed by default.

Real world example, from the link I provided:

> Associating content with multiple sites
>
> The Django-powered sites LJWorld.com and Lawrence.com are operated by
>   the same news organization – the Lawrence Journal-World newspaper in
>   Lawrence, Kansas. LJWorld.com focuses on news, while Lawrence.com
>   focuses on local entertainment. But sometimes editors want to publish
>   an article on both sites.
>
> The brain-dead way of solving the problem would be to require site
>   producers to publish the same story twice: once for LJWorld.com and
>   again for Lawrence.com. But that’s inefficient for site producers, and
>   it’s redundant to store multiple copies of the same story in the
>   database.
>
> The better solution is simple: Both sites use the same article
>   database, and an article is associated with one or more sites.

So instead of a City field, you'd add a field to your model for Site, e.g.:

```
sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
```

You basically have one database that all of your cities use.  Convenient, but I'm wondering how it would scale down the road.  I'm starting a similar project myself and will use the Django sites framework to get the project off the ground.  I'm interested in hearing about a more scalable solution from a database person though.